# Upload script too long to execute

Tags: php, optimization, upload

So, i have a script for resize, save a gif and save a preview image of this gif on my server.

This is my script :

```
public function createImageGif($gif, $x, $y, $w, $h)
    {
        $image = new Imagick();
        $decoded = base64_decode($gif);
        $image->readimageblob($decoded);
        $image = $image->coalesceImages();

        $image_name = uniqid(rand()).'.gif';

        foreach ($image as $frame) { //gif creation
          $frame->cropImage($w, $h, $x, $y);
          $frame->thumbnailImage(117, 135);
          $frame->setImagePage(117, 135, 0, 0);
        }

        $image = $image->deconstructImages();
        $image->writeImages('uploads/profiles/'.$image_name, true);

        //preview creation
        $im = imagecreatefromstring($decoded);
        if ($im !== false) {
            header('Content-Type: image/gif');
            $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor(117, 135);
            imagecopyresampled($newimage, $im, 0, 0, $x, $y, 117, 135, $w, $h);
            imagegif($newimage, 'uploads/profiles-preview/'.$image_name.'', 100);
            imagedestroy($newimage);
            imagedestroy($im);
        }

        return $image_name;
    }
```

So, `$gif` is at first a long string blob (about 2 000 000 characters). At the end, gif size on my server is approximatly 300ko.

This script take more of 20s to execute. I have a good connexion and a good server.

How can i optimize this script ? Any ideas ?

Edit : this is my script for the creation of my data in javascript :

```
var base64data;
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          var reader = new window.FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          reader.onloadend = function() {
            base64data = reader.result;
            img.src = base64data;
          }
```

Comment: Hi Clément. You could put in some breakpoints and get closer to what part of the code "hangs". This might make it a bit easier to help you improve the code. If you are not able to make breakpoints you could make some echo 1; exit; and fint the place where the code "hangs".

Comment: Hum, my problem is not in my PHP script, but in my ajax request. i'm trying to send a very large string with jquery ajax (in my edit the img.src). So, the problem is ajax

Answer (score -1):

Why your script uses a blob binary64 encoded as input? There are many sound reasons to do this thing, but are you sure it's necessary? Can't you just load the image from PHP temp's folder?

Maybe, you're uploading an image from a javascript function, through ajax, base-64 encoding an image (created on the fly from canvas?) and sending it as a string in a POST parameter

Also, I see that you first save your image, then re-open it for sending back the reply to the client. Why don't you send back the image you just resized (the one contained in the $image variable)

Comment: $gif is created with javascript, from the webcam ;) and i haven't understand your third point..

Comment: Forget about third point, I didn't read your code with enough attention. My fault. I encountered the same issue about a year ago, while using a jQuery library for taking screenshots with the camera and I still remember what was the issue in my code: the encoding of the image from javascript to the server! Are you sending your image encoded as base_64, concatenating all the 8 bit values of the pixels? this can explain why your image tends to explode from 300k to 2M before reaching the server. This conversion is *the* issue slowing down the whole thing

Comment: Can you post a little piece of the string being sent to the server? before base64 encoding

Comment: before base64encoding, it's just a blob object. I encode this blob in base64, and i put the data into myImage.src

Comment: My suggestion is to use html's canvas object to convert the image to a png object client side, and the send that object base_64 encoded (as described in the library I linked in the previous comment)